# I have a .dll that I want to edit with the source code. Which files would I need to edit?

Tags: c++, dll, edit, dev-c++

I only want to edit a function in the .dll.

I have these following file types: .c, .h, .lib, .def, and the actual .dll.

Say I want to change a function's parameters from 1 to 2 variables, which files would I need to edit?

Then, how could I compile the files to a new .dll?

I'm using Dev C++.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an exported function (accessible from outside the dll), you need to edit

1. the header (.h file) to add your argument to the function prototype
2. the source (.c file) to handle your new argument in the function body
3. anywhere that calls the function, because now it has to pass an extra argument

Knowing how to compile this to a new dll is a different matter, because we don't know how it was built in the first place. Do you have a makefile or anything?
If not, you'll need to learn how to compile projects in Dev C++.

Comment: No, I don't have a makefile, but I'm sure I can look up how to compile projects. I just wanted to make sure I didn't have to edit all of the files given. Thanks!